# Data rows from database are not displayed in rdlc report

Tags: asp.net, dataset, rdlc

This is my code`

```
  protected void btnCreateBill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayReport();

}
private DataTable TotalInfoData()
{
    try
    {
        // Open Sql Connection  
        SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PRATIKPC;Initial Catalog=dbbilling2.0;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCon.Open();

        // Create a Command  
        SqlCommand SqlComm = new SqlCommand();
        SqlComm.Connection = SqlCon;
        SqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlComm.CommandText = "select * from tblTotalFee where Class='" + ClassDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value + "'and StudentID='" + StudentNameDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value+"'";

        // Create instance of Northwind DataSetXSD  
        DataSet1.tblTotalFeeDataTable TotalInfoData = new DataSet1.tblTotalFeeDataTable();

        // Set a Data Commands  
        SqlDataAdapter SqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlComm);
        SqlDa.Fill(TotalInfoData); // Fill Data in NorthwindDataSet Object.  

        return TotalInfoData;

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
private void DisplayReport()
{
    try
    {
        // Clear the Data Source   
        ReportingForPrintingReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

        // Set a DataSource to the report  

        // First Parameter - Report DataSet Name  
        // Second Parameter - DataSource Object i.e DataTable  
        ReportingForPrintingReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", TotalInfoData()));

        // OR Set Report Path  
        ReportingForPrintingReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc");

        // Refresh and Display Report  
        ReportingForPrintingReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Why isn't any output coming in report?? There are rows in my database but it has not been returned.  My report looks like this after the operation. Why aren't rows being displayed??
[image]

This is my dataset[image]

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: @techdo No there is no exception

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the schema name before the dataset name. Like- `SchemaName_DataSet1`.

```
ReportingForPrintingReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SchemaName_DataSet1", TotalInfoData()));
```

Comment: how can i get schema name of a dataset??